# PostAsync has occurred "the request timed out" on iOS Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, timeout

I use xamarin forms to create an mobile app for Android and iOS. I need to make Http Request, so I use HttpClient.

Here is a simple code of request :

```
var client = new HttpClient();
try
{
   string requestUrl = URL_DATABASE + "xxx";

   var content = new StringContent("{\"param\":\"" + param+ "\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content);

   if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
   {
      var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      return result;
   }

   return "{\"status\":-1}";
}

catch (Exception ex) // Error catched : "the request timed out"
{
   return "{\"status\":-1}";
}
```

I used Postman to check result of my request and work's well, I got good response without timeout.
I noticed that error occurs sometimes but can last an hour.

> error : the request timed out

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, error is in the title and in the code : "the request timed out"

Comment: So, that is it? Nothing more and nothing less? No type information about the exception

Comment: I put a catch and I just get this message by accessing to ```ex.Message```. Can you tell me how to retrieve more information please. Thank's

Comment: We are in local IP address like 192.168.0.17 using xamp in a virtual machine. I noticed error occurs in production which is hosted in OVH

Comment: Did you added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in your manifest?

Comment: Yes I added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true". Moreover issue appears on iOS

Comment: By using wireshark I don't see my POST request. So my request is not done and maybe I'm not able to establish connection with server but WHY ?

Comment: does you app have internet permissions?  Have you tried connecting using the browser on the device to rule out connectivity issues?

Comment: I have internet permission in params (right clic in solution and properties). I also check connexion by going on google. @Jason . It's strange because when I use app I'm not able to make post request with PostAsync and with postman it work's well